$C\subseteq\omega_1$ is closed iff for every $X\subset C$, if $\sup(X)<\omega_1$, then $\sup(X)\in C$.
In the clubs section of Jech's Intro to Set Theory there is the following exercise:

3.1. Prove that an unbounded set $C \subseteq \omega_1$ is closed if and only if for every $X \subset C$, if $\sup(X) < \omega_1$, then $\sup(X) \in C$.

I think I managed to prove it, but I don't see where the hypothesis that $C$ is unbounded is used.
$\textit{Proof.}$ $(\Leftarrow)$ Let $(\alpha_n)_{n\in\omega}$ be an increasing sequence in $C$, we have that $\sup(\alpha_n)<\omega_1$, since $\sup(\alpha_n)=\bigcup\{\alpha_n\}_{n\in\omega}$ is the countable union of at most countable sets $(\alpha_n\in C\subseteq\omega_1)$ then it's countable. Then, by hypothesis, $\sup(\alpha_n)\in C$, so $C$ is closed.
$(\Rightarrow)$ If $C$ is closed, given $X\subset C$ s.t. $\sup(X)=\alpha<\omega_1$, since $\alpha$ is countable, then $X\subseteq\alpha$ will also be countable, and therefore we can index $X=\{X_n\}_{n\in\omega}$ as an increasing sequence. Since $C $ is closed, $\sup(X)\in C$.
Just to pin, a set $C\subseteq\omega_1$ is closed if every increasing sequence $(\alpha_n)_{n\in\omega}$ of ordinals in $C$ has its supremum $\sup\{\alpha_n:n\in\omega\}\in C$.

First I'll note that your "just to pin" is the definition given for a closed subset of $C$ in the book (this was confusing to me at first, since it's not the general definition, but specialized to subsets of $\omega_1$).
Your forward direction isn't quite right. It's not necessarily the case that $X$ will have order-type $\omega$... it could be any countable ordinal. If it is a successor ordinal, the result is trivial.  If it's a longer countable limit ordinal, you can use the countability to recursively pick out a cofinal subset of $X$ that does have order-type $\omega$ and the argument works from there.
You are right that unboundedness is not required.

oh, it's true, tnks. btw, what is the general definition for a closed set?

@Xenônio Closed in the order topology on whatever ordinal we're considering subsets of. You can phrase that more concretely in a lot of ways... one way is very much like the right hand side of this equivalence being proved here, but with $\sup(X)< \omega_1$ replaced by e.g. $\sup(X)< \omega_2$ if we're defining closed subsets of $\omega_2.$
